# SharePoint List permission issue

Tags: list, permissions, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 with Windows Server 2008, using publishing portal template. I have a list in a page. I want to set permission to allow all authenticated (i.e. non-anonymous) user to be able to add new item to the list, but not allow them to change schema (e.g. add a new column, delete a column or create a new view for the list).

What kinds of permission should I set and how to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand you the following based on what you actually want.

1. By giving an user with just **contributor** permission to the site, they will be able to only Add/Edit/Delete and View items.
2. This holds good for all the lists in the site.There is no special changes you need to do.
3. To add **all authenticated user** to the Contributor group follow the below steps
4. Site Action -> Site Settings->People And Groups-> Select **[YourSiteName] Members** Group in the Left navigation
5. Say New User and in the  Users/Groups: Select the **Add all authenticated users**  in the left side. Thats it you will get what you want.

Option Two:

1. Say you want to give all authenticated users with the readonly permission and want them to allow to add/edit/delete only on a particular list then you will have to follow  Emon steps.
2. Go to View All Site Content - >Select the List you want to give permission.
3. Settings->List Settings->Permission for this List -> Action -> Edit Permission->Say Ok->Select all the users->Action->Remove User Permission->Say Okay.
4. At this stage what it means is that this List will not be able to access by any one expect the Site owners.
5. Now you select Add the users you want -> Select the option Give users permission directly - > And Select Contributor. [This is what it means to break the inheritance and assign permission]

Comment: Cool, Kusek! Question answered!

Answer (score 2):

First you might need to break permission inheritance for the list. Then giving the authenticated users "Contributor" rights will only allow them post items and nothing else.

Comment: "break permission inheritance for the list" -- can you show me how to do this please?